# Run a second query if first query is empty with a single query

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have one query A that should be composed of two queries A.1 and A.2. My goal is to make A.2 be run only if query A.1 returns no data. Is this even possible? I tried to add count(x), but it doesn't seem to do anything. Here I leave off with the example. I have been trying to use AantalLln >0 in the where clause with a select within a select, but no luck. Perhaps a union with a conditional statement?

```
//Query A

//Query A.1
SELECT  LE_AGENDA_FK, LE_CODE, LE_ID, LE_KLAS_FK, LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, LE_OMSCHRIJVING, LE_VERANDERDDOOR, LE_VERANDERDOP , 
Count(LH_ID) As AantalLln  
FROM  LESEENHEID 
left JOIN LOOPBAANLESEENHEID on (LH_LESEENHEID_FK = LE_ID)  
left JOIN LOOPBAAN ON (LH_LOOPBAAN_FK = LB_ID)    
 WHERE 
 ('2022/09/28' BETWEEN LB_VAN AND LB_TOT) 
 AND   
 (LE_ID in (8277))  
 GROUP BY  
 LE_AGENDA_FK, 
 LE_CODE, LE_ID, 
 LE_KLAS_FK, 
 LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK,
 LE_OMSCHRIJVING, 
 LE_VERANDERDDOOR, 
 LE_VERANDERDOP
  
//Query A.2
SELECT LE_AGENDA_FK, LE_CODE, LE_ID, LE_KLAS_FK, LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, LE_OMSCHRIJVING, LE_VERANDERDDOOR, LE_VERANDERDOP,0 As AantalLln
FROM  LESEENHEID
WHERE (LE_ID in (8277))
ORDER BY LE_ID ROWS 1000
```

Comment: I suppose LE is LESEENHEID, LH is LOOPBAANLESEENHEID and LB is LOOPBAAN? And you want to get the LB count for LE 8277 only, i.e. one row? And if the query returns no row (because the dates don't match), you want to select a count of 0 for all the LE? Why the `ORDER BY` clause, when it is just one row you are showing?

Comment: use "selectable stored procedure" to contain this query switch logic, and select from that procedure in your program

Comment: your question seems inconsistent with your other questions. Do you really want to prohibit all the second query for the whole table, or only for a specific LE_ID (assuming LE_ID alone is PK) ??? If you want per-ID filtering then standard trick with OUTER JOIN and NULL check should work.  `with Q1 as (....), Q2 as (....)  select * from Q1 UNION ALL select * from (select * from Q2 left join Q1 on Q1.LE_ID = Q2.LE_ID where Q1.LE_ID is NULL)` - however this might work really slow if database was not optimized and Q1 works without indexes

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
With LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN as (
   SELECT  LE_AGENDA_FK, LE_CODE, LE_ID , LE_KLAS_FK, LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, LE_OMSCHRIJVING, LE_VERANDERDDOOR, LE_VERANDERDOP , 
Count(LH_ID) As AantalLln
FROM  LESEENHEID 
inner JOIN LOOPBAANLESEENHEID on (LH_LESEENHEID_FK = LE_ID)  
inner JOIN LOOPBAAN ON (LH_LOOPBAAN_FK = LB_ID)   
 WHERE 
 ('2022/09/28' BETWEEN LB_VAN AND LB_TOT) 
 AND   
 (LE_ID in (8276)) 
 GROUP BY  
 LE_AGENDA_FK, 
 LE_CODE, LE_ID, 
 LE_KLAS_FK, 
 LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK,
  LE_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  LE_VERANDERDDOOR, 
  LE_VERANDERDOP  ,
  LB_VAN,
  LB_TOT
) 
,  LESEENHEIDLOOPBAANNULL AS (
   SELECT  LE_AGENDA_FK, LE_CODE, LE_ID, LE_KLAS_FK, LE_KLASPARTITIE_FK, LE_OMSCHRIJVING, LE_VERANDERDDOOR, LE_VERANDERDOP,0 As AantalLln 
   FROM  LESEENHEID   
   where   LE_ID in (8276) and  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN)
  )
SELECT * FROM LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM LESEENHEIDLOOPBAANNULL;
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets for languages other than HTML, CSS or JavaScript. For SQL, use a normal code block (indented by four spaces, or within a code-fence (triple backticks).

Comment: It is not a solution for the task you were asking about. Both queries will be run anyway (besides much bigger number of times awfully dropping performance). Only PSQL block can prevent second query from being run completely.

Comment: @user13964273 that is not entirely true. Interbase/Firebird strives to be "lazy computation" engine. So the 2nd query would be prepared, indeed. But probably would only be evaluated if the rows are actually pulled to the client (given `union all` mode, not `union distinct`).  This way, `Select 1, ....  UNION ALL Select 2, ....` should probably kind of work. On the first fetch your program remembers the  value of the first column, and as soon as it changes - you close the query without reading the rest

Comment: granted, this specific solution is indeen awful: `and  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LESEENHEIDLOOPBAAN)` woudl really be run again and again for the 2nd query, whic hwould scale pretty bad if database has any data. But in general this is doable.